# Is there a Hook like \AtEndDocument for the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, tocstyle, tocbasic

I have written a document class, and I need to change the page numbering.
The table of contents should use roman style page numbering, the rest should use arabic.

It would be great if it was possible to solve this in the class file, I am using the `tocbasic` package with Koma Script. It would also be great if the user could use `\tableofcontents` like in every other document.

It should look like this for the users:

```
\documentclass[stuff]{myclass}

\title{my title}
\author{me}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{one}
Important text.

\section{section one}
Not so important text.

\end{document}
```

Code in class-file `myclass.cls`, thanks to @esdd:

```
\BeforeTOCHead[toc]{\frontmatter}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\mainmatter}
```

Comment: It's quite unclear. The document class `book` and similar classes are using `\frontmatter` with page numbering `roman` and `\mainmatter` with page numbering `arabic`. However, the front matter part is not limited to the table of contents. Also, other lists (for figures, tables, or acronyms) and chapters (with preface, acknowledgments) belong to the front matter part.

Comment: I use `scrbook` as base for my class but i want the page numbering to do everything I want automatically.

Comment: @Patrick Using `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` is the correct way to go. They're not difficult to type and help in marking up the document; you gain nothing by obscuring your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tocbasic` has some hooks. You can use

```
\BeforeTOCHead[toc]{\frontmatter}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\mainmatter}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{scrbook}% loads tocbasic automatically
\BeforeTOCHead[toc]{\frontmatter}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\mainmatter}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{One}
\chapter{Two}
\end{document}
```

---

Example with a TOC that is longer than one page:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}% loads tocbasic automatically
\BeforeTOCHead[toc]{\frontmatter}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\mainmatter}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this before posting here, but if your table of contents is longer than one page, your `\mainmatter` will start on the second page of your table of contents.

Comment: `\AfterStartingTOC` is a hook that is executed after `\@starttoc`, i.e. after the TOC file has been read and processed. I have added an example with a two page TOC. There you can see that `\mainmatter` starts after the last page of the TOC.

Comment: I just tried it again and now it worked, seems like I did something wrong the first time.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the `scrbook` document class, you could proceed by providing the following instructions in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\tableofcontents}{\frontmatter}{}{}
\apptocmd{\tableofcontents}{\mainmatter}{}{}
```

Assuming your document has `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures`, *and* `\listoftables` instructions (in this order), you'd write

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\tableofcontents}{\frontmatter}{}{}
\apptocmd{\listoftables}{\mainmatter}{}{}
```

to have roman numerals for the page numbers of these three document units, followed by arabic numerals for the subsequent material.

---

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\tableofcontents}{\frontmatter}{}{}
\apptocmd{\tableofcontents}{\mainmatter}{}{}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Uno}
\chapter{Due}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I just had to make a little change. I put those two commands into  `\AtBeginDocument{}`, so it did exactly what I want.